# What is the file Docker-publish.sh and how it was created?

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net

I followed the [example](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility) to publish a asp.net application to a docker container. Basically a Dockerfile is in the PublishProfiles folder that gets created in your Visual Studio project under "Properties."

Then we can use the command from PowerShell or Linux. I understand how it works in PowerShell but I don't understand the command from Linux.

```
cd ProjectFolder (like WebApplication/src/WebApplication)
source dnvm.sh
dnu restore --no-cache
mkdir ~/Temp
dnu publish . --out ~/Temp/ --wwwroot-out "wwwroot" --quiet
cd Properties/PublishProfiles
chmod +x ./Docker-publish.sh
./Docker-publish.sh ./Docker.pubxml ~/Temp/
```

My question is that what is the file `Docker-publish.sh` here and how it was created?

I assume that it was generated by [DNX Utility](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility) and why it has such a name? What is the context then?

Answer (score 0):

I may find the answer. Microsoft used that docker tools can generate a sh file. However it updated the tools afterwards, that shell file was gone then. The latest tools just skip that shell file.

Lucky I have the old tools backed up. It reads a xml file and run the process.

```
        #!/bin/bash

    # Publish an application to Docker container
    # Please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=529706 to learn more about the scirpt

    set -e

    if ! type docker &>/dev/null; then
        echo "Unable to find docker command. Please install it first"
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ "$#" != "2" ]; then
        echo "Usage: $0 PubxmlFilePath PackOutputFolderPath"
        exit 1
    fi

    pubxmlFilePath="$1"

    if [ ! -e "$pubxmlFilePath" ]; then
        echo "Unable to find publish settings xml file: $pubxmlFilePath"
        exit 1
    fi

    packOutputFolderPath="$2"

    if [ ! -d "$packOutputFolderPath" ]; then
        echo "Unable to find pack output folder: $packOutputFolderPath"
        exit 1
    fi

    projectName=$(basename "$( cd -P "$(dirname "$pubxmlFilePath" )/../.." && pwd )")

    publishProfilesFolderPath=$packOutputFolderPath/approot/src/$projectName/Properties/PublishProfiles

    if [ ! -d "$publishProfilesFolderPath" ]; then
        echo "Unble to find publish profiles folder : $publishProfilesFolderPath."
        exit 1
    fi

    # Parse publish settings xml file
    dockerServerUrl=$(grep -Eo '<DockerServerUrl>.+</DockerServerUrl>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    dockerImageName=$(grep -Eo '<DockerImageName>.+</DockerImageName>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    dockerfileRelativePath=$(grep -Eo '<DockerfileRelativePath>.+</DockerfileRelativePath>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    dockerPublishHostPort=$(grep -Eo '<DockerPublishHostPort>.+</DockerPublishHostPort>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    dockerPublishContainerPort=$(grep -Eo '<DockerPublishContainerPort>.+</DockerPublishContainerPort>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    dockerAuthOptions=$(grep -Eo '<DockerAuthOptions>.+</DockerAuthOptions>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    dockerRunOptions=$(grep -Eo '<DockerRunOptions>.+</DockerRunOptions>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    dockerAppType=$(grep -Eo '<DockerAppType>.+</DockerAppType>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    dockerBuildOnly=$(grep -Eo '<DockerBuildOnly>.+</DockerBuildOnly>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    dockerRemoveConflictingContainers=$(grep -Eo '<DockerRemoveConflictingContainers>.+</DockerRemoveConflictingContainers>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    siteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish=$(grep -Eo '<SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>.+</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    launchSiteAfterPublish=$(grep -Eo '<LaunchSiteAfterPublish>.+</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')
    createWindowsContainer=$(grep -Eo '<CreateWindowsContainer>.+</CreateWindowsContainer>' "$pubxmlFilePath" | awk -F'[<>]' '{print $3}')

    echo "==== Publish Settings ===="
    echo "DockerServerUrl: $dockerServerUrl"
    echo "DockerImageName: $dockerImageName"
    echo "DockerfileRelativePath: $dockerfileRelativePath"
    echo "DockerPublishHostPort: $dockerPublishHostPort"
    echo "DockerPublishContainerPort: $dockerPublishContainerPort"
    echo "DockerAuthOptions: $dockerAuthOptions"
    echo "DockerRunOptions: $dockerRunOptions"
    echo "DockerAppType: $dockerAppType"
    echo "DockerBuildOnly: $dockerBuildOnly"
    echo "DockerRemoveConflictingContainers: $dockerRemoveConflictingContainers"
    echo "SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish: $siteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish"
    echo "LaunchSiteAfterPublish: $launchSiteAfterPublish"
    echo "CreateWindowsContainer: $createWindowsContainer"
    echo "=========================="

    echo "Creating Dockerfile..."

    if [ "$dockerfileRelativePath" == "" ]; then
        dockerfilePath=$publishProfilesFolderPath/Dockerfile
    else
        dockerfilePath=$publishProfilesFolderPath/${dockerfileRelativePath//\\/\/}
    fi

    if [ ! -e "$dockerfilePath" ]; then
        echo "Unble to find DockerFile : $dockerFilePath"
        exit 1
    fi

    if [ "$dockerRemoveConflictingContainers" == "True" ] && [ $dockerPublishHostPort ]; then
        echo "Docker command: docker $dockerAuthOptions -H $dockerServerUrl ps -a"
        if [ "$createWindowsContainer" == "True" ]; then
            conflictingContainers=$(docker "$dockerAuthOptions" -H "$dockerServerUrl" ps -a | grep "$dockerPublishHostPort_$dockerPublishContainerPort" | awk '{print $1}')
        else
            conflictingContainers=$(docker "$dockerAuthOptions" -H "$dockerServerUrl" ps -a | grep ":$dockerPublishHostPort->" | awk '{print $1}')
        fi

        if [ $conflictingContainers ]; then
            echo "Removing conflicting containers: $conflictingContainers"
            echo "Docker command: docker $dockerAuthOptions -H $dockerServerUrl rm -f $conflictingContainers"
            if [ "$createWindowsContainer" == "True" ]; then
                docker "$dockerAuthOptions" -H "$dockerServerUrl" rm -f "$conflictingContainers" || true
                sleep 3
                docker "$dockerAuthOptions" -H "$dockerServerUrl" rm -f "$conflictingContainers" || true
            else
                docker "$dockerAuthOptions" -H "$dockerServerUrl" rm -f "$conflictingContainers"
            fi
        fi
    fi

    echo "Building docker image $dockerImageName..."
    echo "Docker command: docker $dockerAuthOptions -H $dockerServerUrl build -t $dockerImageName -f $dockerfilePath $packOutputFolderPath"
    docker "$dockerAuthOptions" -H "$dockerServerUrl" build -t "$dockerImageName" -f "$dockerfilePath" "$packOutputFolderPath"

    if [ "$dockerBuildOnly" == "False" ]; then
        echo "Starting docker container: $dockerImageName..."

        publishPort=""
        envVars=""
        containerName=""

        if [ $dockerPublishHostPort ] && [ $dockerPublishContainerPort ]; then
            publishPort=" -p $dockerPublishHostPort:$dockerPublishContainerPort"
            if [ "$dockerAppType" == "Web" ]; then 
                envVars=" -e server.urls=http://*:$dockerPublishContainerPort"
            fi
            if [ "$createWindowsContainer" == "True" ]; then 
                containerName=" --name $dockerPublishHostPort_$dockerPublishContainerPort
            fi
        fi

        echo "Docker command: docker $dockerAuthOptions -H $dockerServerUrl run -t -d$publishPort$envVars $dockerRunOptions $dockerImageName"
        containerId=$(docker "$dockerAuthOptions" -H "$dockerServerUrl" run -t -d$publishPort$envVars$containerName $dockerRunOptions "$dockerImageName")
        echo "New container started with id: $containerId"

        echo -e "To see standard output from your application, execute the command:\ndocker $dockerAuthOptions -H $dockerServerUrl logs --follow $containerId"
        echo "Publish completed successfully."

        if [ "$launchSiteAfterPublish" == "True" ]; then
            if [ "$siteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish" == "" ]; then
                url="http://"$(expr "$dockerServerUrl" : '.*//\(.*\:\)')$dockerPublishHostPort
            else
                url=$siteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish
            fi

            echo "Attempting to connect to $url..."

            set +e
            i=0
            while [ $i -lt 5 ]
            do
                curl -s --head $url --max-time 10 | head -n 1 | grep "HTTP/1.[01] [23]..."

                if [ $? == 0 ]; then
                    if [ -e "/Applications/Safari.app" ]; then
                        open -a /Applications/Safari.app $url
                    elif [ -e "/usr/bin/firefox" ]; then
                        firefox $url &>/dev/null &
                    else
                        echo -e "To see the web content, execute the command:\ncurl $url"
                    fi

                    exit
                fi

                sleep 5
                i=$((i+1))
            done

            logs=$(docker "$dockerAuthOptions" -H "$dockerServerUrl" logs "$containerId")
            echo -e "Failed to connect to $url. If your Docker host is an Azure virtual machine, please make sure to set up the endpoint $dockerPublishContainerPort using the Azure portal.\nContainer logs:\n$logs\nPlease visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=529706 for troubleshooting guide."
        fi

    else
        echo "Publish completed successfully. The container was not started because the DockerBuildOnly flag was set to True."
    fi
```